# in [objective C] whats is better: if(variable) or if(variable != nil)?

Tags: objective-c

I have seen in several places the use of if(variable != nil), I personally prefer if(variable) because we avoid a comparison operation. Some one can explain me please whats the better approach and most important, why! Thanks.

Comment: This question was asked literally 1-2 days ago. And it is still off-topic.

Comment: No reason to be down voting this. Its a valid question.

Comment: @logixologist No reason to be upvoting this. It's a valid but off-topic and duplicate question.

Comment: some use `if(nil != variable)` instead `if(variable != nil)`

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes there is. Its countering a unwarranted downvote. Though I understand the need to give feedback but I only downvote when its absolutely necessary. Others will choose to downvote if they dont like the title or they personally know the answer they think its a dumb question. This is one question I have always wanted to ask but was afraid to get into downvote hell by doing so.

Comment: @logixologist The downvote is not unwarranted, and anyway, upvotes are not there for countering downvotes.

Comment: @logixologist I didn't do any voting but keep in mind that one use of down voting is to indicate that the question shows no effort prior to asking the question - even if it is a good question. Looking for duplicates should be part of that effort. And I must agree that up voting for the sake of countering a down vote is inappropriate. Only up vote if the question truly merits an up vote. Not because you disagree with a down vote.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler will optimize the comparison out anyway, there won't be any differences in the generated code.

It's just a question of style, and possibly readability, really.

Comment: There's no "optimization" in that either. A comparison **is** made against the null pointer in both cases (since the two forms are equivalent).

Comment: It's a **definition** of `if(variable)`: *In both forms, the ﬁrst substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0.* http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf

Comment: @H2CO3 - There *is* an optimisation here, and its as old as the hills. See comment on accept answer to duped question.

Comment: @CRD No, that's not quite an optimization.

Answer (score 2):

> if(variable) because we avoid a comparison operation
>
> The compiler will optimize the comparison out anyway

It's a **definition** of `if(variable)`: *In both forms, the ﬁrst substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0.* http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf

And `nil` is defined as `0` pointer.

So the correct way is to say that `if (variable)` is defined as `if (variable!=nil)` whenever `variable` is a  pointer.

> It's just a question of style,

You can make a big mistake by omitting a first symbol in `!=` or `==`, so it's a pretty standard advice to avoid using `if(variable==nil)` and `if(variable!=nil)`. Although clang should warn you anyway.